# Installing chromium-browser version 76.x on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, chromium, browser

I am trying to install Chromium-browser 76.x on ubuntu 18.04.

The command `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` by default installs version 78.x.

How can I check the available options of chromium browser packages?

Also, `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser=76` resulted in an error:

> E: Version '76' for 'chromium-browser' was not found

Comment: I don't think 76 is available for 18.04 but You can try to install 75 : https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/chromium-browser

Comment: `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser=75`, says that it cannot find version 75

Comment: May I please know about how to check the available versions?

Comment: Download it from here and install using `sudo dpkg -i [filename]` : https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/chromium-browser/download

Comment: Well, its resulting in an  installation error. Followed by `sudo apt-get install -f` command installs version 78.X